# UI Bug in User Profile page

Tags: bug

While visiting this [user](https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/users/10894/202-accepted)'s profile page, I encountered a UI bug.

Here's a screenshot:

[image: Bad UI]

As you can see, the text provided in the profile didn't wrap itself in the center, instead if pushed the right div or whatever (I am not that expert with html/css).

I am using Chrome Version 69.0.3497.100 (Official Build) (64-bit), Windows 7.

Note that by visiting his other SE profile page, this bug didn't appear.

Comment: True, it's been like that for a while. Here's the report on [Main Meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/316305/369802)

Comment: Though, I don't see the bug on Mozilla Firefox but on Google Chrome on Ubuntu 16.04. So, it's kinda issue on Google Chrome.

Comment: Yeah, could be. Browsers does act very different sometimes. They just hate front end developers.

Comment: The bug report on [MSO](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/375028/6380541) says it can occur in Firefox too ;)